# Windows 10: Input Indicator disappears everytime I reboot

Tags: windows-10, reboot, input-languages

After OS reinstall, I have a tiny, but annoying problem. The keyboard input indicator in the taskbar disappears after every reboot. Also, I cannot change the input method by the appropriate keyboard shortcut.

To clarify: I'm able to display it by changing the input method in the Settings app, but it won't survive the next reboot.

As I'm aware, I have everything set up so I should see the input indicator, specifically:

1. I have the input indicator set toggle set to on in Settings -> Personalization -> Taskbar -> Select which icons appear on the taskbar
2. I have multiple input methods.
3. In Time & Language -> Language -> Keyboard -> Language bar options, I have the Language Bar radio button set to Docked in the taskbar

Any ideas about what can I do to keep the Input Indicator and language switching working after restart?

Comment: Hi, here is a similar thread discussed before, you could check if the method mentioned in this thread was helpful to you:[RE : INPUT INDICATOR MISSING](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-other_settings-winpc/re-input-indicator-missing/e4053ceb-fc7f-4bdc-9514-df182a232d16)

Comment: @Sunny the problem seems similar, however, the thread is without an answer and obviously dead.

Comment: `tasklist | findstr /I "ctfmon TextInputHost"` should show both tasks. Otherwise, [take a look](https://windowsdot.com/2-quick-ways-to-enable-ctfmon-exe-on-startup-windows-10/)…